# Marking boundary from list of Latitude and Longitude

Tags: maps, tableau-api, latitude-longitude

I am working on Tableau Maps. Need your help to mark boundary on Tableau Maps with help of given latitude and longitude. I have list of latitude and longitude for garden area, from that I want to show garden boundary with some heatmap.

---

How to achieve it ? Do we need some mathematical calculation for finding it ?

[image]

Comment: Interesting question, Can you provide more info? like are you looking for heat map inside the boundry? Also boundry latitudes and longitudes are included in current map of those are different ? if possible attach workbook with dummy data

Comment: Thanks @Siva .. Can you assume dummy data for your understanding . You can take any polygon area for reference. I am good with that